# what would be a good way to have a day background and night backgroud switch over with time am pm?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RandomiseBackGround : MonoBehaviour {

    public SpriteRenderer BackgroundSpriteRenderer;
    public Sprite[] backgroundSprites;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        //atm i am just randomising two backgrounds i have built just untill i can     
        //figure out how to change them based on am pm if its doable??

        BackgroundSpriteRenderer.sprite = backgroundSprites[Random.Range(0, backgroundSprites.Length)];
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just state from 07.00 till 22.00. unstead of AM/PM?

Comment: im not sure on how i could get the backgrounds to change based on say your mobile devices time settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class RandomiseBackGround : MonoBehaviour
{

    public SpriteRenderer BackgroundSpriteRenderer;
    public Sprite[] backgroundSprites;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        int dayStart = 7;
        int dayStop = 22;
        if(DateTime.Now.Hour > dayStart && DateTime.Now.Hour < dayStop)
        {
            //Display background by day
        }else
        {
            //Display background by night
        }
    }
```

Is this what you're looking for? You could adjust it to use the PM/AM method..

Comment: how would i implement the day and night backgrounds in unity to this ? by getComponent??

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

      public SpriteRenderer BackgroundSpriteRenderer;
        public Sprite DayBackground;
        public Sprite NightBackground;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
        {
            int dayStart = 7;
            int dayStop = 22;
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour > dayStart && DateTime.Now.Hour < dayStop)
            {
                //Display background by day
                BackgroundSpriteRenderer.sprite = DayBackground;
            }
            else
            {
                //Display background by night**strong text**
                BackgroundSpriteRenderer.sprite = NightBackground;
            }
        }
    }
```